# Нужно написать функцию чтоб получилось [5,10,15,20] при вызове f(arr,2)

Tags: javascript

```
let arr = [10, 20, 30, 40];

console.log(f(arr,2))//[5,10,15,20]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let arr = [10, 20, 30, 40];

console.log(f(arr,2))

function f(arr, divided)
{
    return arr.map(el => el / divided);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let arr = [10, 20, 30, 40];

const f = (array, divider) => array.map(item => item / divider);

console.log(f(arr, 2));
```